# str_replace when matched and followed by space or special characters

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a working function that strips profanity words.

The word list is compose of 1700 bad words.

My problem is that it censored

> 'badwords '

but not

> 'badwords.' , 'badwords' and the like.

If I chose to remove space after

> $badword[$key] = $word;

instead of

> $badword[$key] = $word." ";

then I would have a bigger problem because if the bad word is **CON** then it will stripped a word **CONSTANT**

My question is, how can i strip a WORD followed by special characters except space?

> badword. badword# badword,

.

```
function badWordFilter($data)
{
    $wordlist = file_get_contents("badwordsnew.txt");
    $words = explode(",", $wordlist);


    $badword = array();
    $replacementword = array();


    foreach ($words as $key => $word) 
    {
       $badword[$key] = $word." ";
       $replacementword[$key] = addStars($word);
    }


    return str_ireplace($badword,$replacementword,$data);
}


function addStars($word) 
{
    $length = strlen($word);

    return "*" . substr($word, 1, 1) . str_repeat("*", $length - 2)." " ;
}
```

Comment: don't you want to use regex ?

Comment: @splash58 I'm ok with it as long as it will work :)

Comment: preg_replace() .. Its work for you try with this ..

Comment: something as `preg_replace('/'\b' .$badword . '(s)?\b/i',$replacementword.'$1',$data);`

Comment: @splash58 I'm not good at preg_replace. Your code gave me an error, maybe because the $badword is an ARRAY?

Comment: some minutes. I will be back and try to make a draft

Comment: Plural forms would be hard, you can use word boundaries for an exact word though.

Comment: Check out if [this regex demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/794899) is of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question with the help of @maxchehab answer, but I can't declared his answer because it has fault at some area. I am posting this answer so others can use this code when they need a BAD WORD FILTER.

```
function badWordFinder($data)
{
    $data = " " . $data . " ";  //adding white space at the beginning and end of $data will help stripped bad words located at the begging and/or end.        

    $badwordlist = "bad,words,here,comma separated,no space before and after the word(s),multiple word is allowed"; //file_get_contents("badwordsnew.txt"); //
    $badwords = explode(",", $badwordlist);

    $capturedBadwords = array();


    foreach ($badwords as $bad) 
    {
        if(stripos($data, $bad))
        {
            array_push($capturedBadwords, $bad);
        }             
    }

    return badWordFilter($data, $capturedBadwords);
}


function badWordFilter($data, array $capturedBadwords)
{

    $specialCharacters = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+",".",","," "];

    foreach ($specialCharacters as $endingAt) 
    {
      foreach ($capturedBadwords as $bad) 
      {
          $data = str_ireplace($bad.$endingAt, addStars($bad), $data);   
      }                  
    }

    return trim($data);
}  


function addStars($bad) 
{
    $length = strlen($bad);

    return "*" . substr($bad, 1, 1) . str_repeat("*", $length - 2)." ";
}


$str = 'i am bad words but i cant post it here because it is not allowed by the website some bad words# here with bad. ending in specia character but my code is badly strong so i can captured and striped those bad words.';



echo "$str<br><br>";

echo badWordFinder($str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `$data` is a text that needs to be censored, `badWordFilter()` will return the text with bad words as `*`.

```
function badWordFilter($data)
{
    $wordlist = file_get_contents("badwordsnew.txt");



    $words = explode(",", $wordlist);

    $specialCharacters = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+",".",",",""];

    $dataList = explode(" ", $data);

    $output = "";

    foreach ($dataList as $check) 
    {
        $temp = $check;
        $doesContain = contains($check, $words);
        if($doesContain != false){
            foreach($specialCharacters as $character){
                if($check == $doesContain . $character || $check == $character . $doesContain ){
                    $temp = addStars($doesContain);
                }
            }
        }

        $output .= $temp . " ";
    }


    return $output;
}

function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return $a;
    }
    return false;
}


function addStars($word) 
{
    $length = strlen($word);

    return "*" . substr($word, 1, 1) . str_repeat("*", $length - 2)." " ;
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f39415fc6ee6e77e2282d25edc51857dd7653e0)

Comment: Can you provide more information? I substituted my own "badwordsnew.txt" as a string in the Sandbox link provided. Make sure you are using the code posted in my answer.

Comment: this is sample of the text. The one at the top is the original. http://imgur.com/a/HWkOF

Comment: Double check if constant is in your badwordsnew.txt

Comment: the word "constant" was not included. The word was stripped because it has "CON" which is included on the badwords

Comment: This comes down to design. Besides making certain exceptions, allowing bad words to not be censored if they are inside of a word will enable words like "badword$" to escape the test. I think the best solution here is to remove CON from badwordsnew.txt

Comment: I should mention, when I substituted the entire badwordsnew.txt for $wordlist the error that you reported does not show.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/833336792d2dc971b52326ab9ee175be90a5c267

Comment: there are lot of words with ASS, and other words which are considered bad words

Comment: it is not CASE INSENSITIVE. By the way thanks for the help. I adjusted your code and also posted my answer here.